# Images showing up in my app that are not in there

Tags: android, image

I published a version of my app and it had 10 photos in it.  I then took 5 of those photos out and replaced with 5 different ones.  My question is why on earth when I publish the new version of my app that the original 10 are still there when 5 of them are not even in any of my /res directories (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi)?

Can anyone shed some light on this?  Because this is very crucial for my app on the market.

Comment: How long did you wait after publishing the new app? Sometimes Google's servers need to take some time (hours, maybe) to distribute the new version of the app.

Comment: @GregHewgill It is coming up on the 1 hour 30 minute mark since it hit the market.

Comment: You can check the version number shown on the app page to see whether it has been updated to your latest. Google requires the version numbers to be unique so you can use this to know for sure.

Comment: @GregHewgill The version numbers are correct.  These images are no where in my eclipse at all.  I then created a signed export and it got published but it still shows the old images :(.

Comment: Well, there's not much information for us to go on here. The correct files are either in your apk, or they aren't.

Comment: @GregHewgill I wish there was more information to give.

Answer (score 0):

There ended up being another /res folder in my /bin which was holding all the older images and for some reason when I had the newer images on there it wouldn't replace them inside the /res in the /bin area.